# Json key and value in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, axios

My Link json test file is the following:

```
[{"google" : "https://google.com"},{"bing" : "https://bing.com"}]
```

The javascript requesting the value, using axios:

```
var Links = './Links'

axios.get(Links)
 .then(function(response){
  console.log(response.data["google"]);
  try {
    var Test12 = JSON.stringify(response.data["google"]);
  } catch (err) {
    var Test12 = 'nothing'
  }
```

The result is undefined.

My goal is to return the value of the input "google" or any input from the JSON and store it in the var as a string.

Comment: You've got an array of objects, so you'll have to search the array for objects that contain a property name you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its an array of objects so you should access the values like,

```
response.data[0].google
```

**OR**

```
response.data[0]["google"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data file is a list with two objects in it.

To access the google item you should access the list element.

```
var Test12 = JSON.stringify(response.data[0]["google"]);
```

Although I would change the json file to:

```
{"google" : "https://google.com", "bing" : "https://bing.com"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var data=[{"google" : "https://google.com"},{"bing" : "https://bing.com"}];


data.forEach(function(el, index) {
    Object.keys(el).forEach(function(val) {
        console.log(val + " => " + el[val]);
    });
});
```